# Vue.js devtools window not showing

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, vuejs3, vue-devtools

So I had never used Vue.js before, after I learned some basic concepts I created a new project via the Vue CLI. I've been working on it and received different errors (I still have a lot to learn) so I looked up a way to debug easily.

I'm using WebStorm as IDE and Chrome as browser. I added the [Vue.js devtools extension to Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd), ran the project through `npm run serve` and opened up the devtool console.

The extension says Vue is detected on the page but the Vue window doesn't show up.

- Chrome is at its the latest version
- I removed other extensions like AdBlocker
- reloaded the page
- closed and restarted the browser and later on also the computer

I then found this other extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg
removed the first one, added this and did the same things.

Still doesn't work. Should I add something to my code maybe?

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">


    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="imag_container">
      <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo ITIS">
    </div>
    <KioskParagraphSlider id="slider"/>
    <EventsCalendar id="calendar"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import KioskParagraphSlider from './components/KioskParagraphSlider.vue'
import EventsCalendar from './components/EventsCalendar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    KioskParagraphSlider, EventsCalendar
  }
}
</script>

<style>
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 7fr;
}
#calendar{
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
</style>
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "kiosk",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Obviously there are many other files.

Hope any of you can help me.

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome, probably. Try using Chrome Canary.

Comment: nope, still doesn't work

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your inspector windows in chrome please ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
There was an error generated by one of my components (it was the reason why I wanted the devtools), it turned out that the error was preventig the devtools window from showing (don't know why), the window showed when I commented the component.

Answer (score -2):

You mentioned *"the vue window"*, so you might be expecting a new window to appear, but it's actually a panel in DevTools, and that does not *automatically* open.

To open the Vue DevTools panel:

1. Open [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/#chrome).
2. If the "Vue" panel is not visible in the tab list at the top of DevTools, click the tab menu expander to view other available tabs.

   [image]
3. Select "Vue" from the menu:

   [image]
4. Observe the Vue DevTools panel appears:

   [image]