# Vue devtools not working with Vue 3 Custom Elements

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, vue-devtools

I am using Vue 3 components purely as [custom elements](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) (in ASP.NET MVC views).  When I view my site on localhost, after using vue-cli-service to make a non-prod build of the Vue components (all are .ce.vue), the Vue devtools icon "lights up" (in the browser's extensions icons toolbar) indicating that it detects Vue on the page--however, the Vue tab never appears in the Chrome dev tools.

**Should the Vue devtools extension work with just Vue custom elements on a page?**  I tried the troubleshooting steps in [the F.A.Q.](https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/faq.html#the-vue-devtools-don-t-show-up), but none seem to apply.  (I also turned off all other extensions and restarted my browser.)

Note: I am using a 32" 4k monitor, so I am definitely seeing the full Chrome dev tools UI.
[image: Image of Chrome dev tools for the page hosting the Vue custom element]

Note 2: I have tried using the Vue devtools with my custom element rendered in a shadow DOM and without one.

Without a shadow DOM:
[image: Without a shadow DOM]

With a shadow DOM
[image: With a shadow DOM]

Here is a link to the Vue.js GitHub issue with a helpful comment for the PR for making the shadow DOM wrapper optional.

[defineCustomElement without shadowDom #4314](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4314#issuecomment-1021393430)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71444355/vue-js-devtools-window-not-showing/71445969#71445969

Comment: The Vue devtools tab is often hidden as it appears last in the tab list. Have you checked the tab list menu?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @tony19, but that is not the issue.  I added a clarifying note to the question.

Comment: Have you tried the [standalone version](https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#standalone) ? Custom elements are actually WebComponents and they incapsulate their JavaScript and DOM behind a Shadow DOM - so probably DevTools can not connect through the Shadow. There is also [Vue-Inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-inspector) but my advice is to debug your application(s) before their building as WebComponents.

Comment: Thanks, @IVOGELOV, you raise an interesting point.  I have now addressed it in the second note I just added to my question.